# UITableView does not always fire delegate methods when tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios6

I have a UITableView set up with some custom cells.

I've turned on cell highlighting just testing purposes, so that I can see the cell is responding to my touch.

The cell will highlight, but the tableview doesn't fire `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` UNLESS I tap and hold the cell for a long time ( > 3 seconds).

Any idea why the delegates aren't firing on normal taps?

I was thinking it could be due to a complex view hierarchy, but my hierarchy is not very crazy.

Comment: Do you have any custom touch handling or gesture recognizers anywhere in the view hierarchy?

Comment: I do...as soon as you responded, I tried not adding those, and the delegates fire immediately...

Comment: I'm not expert on this but the concept is that if a tap might possibly be either a simple gesture or the start of a more complicated one, the OS has to wait until the complicated one is no longer possible (timed out) before it can decide that the simple one is correct.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you answer the question so I can accept it for ya?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments....

The delay seems to be caused by the interaction of multiple gesture handlers.  The concept is that if a tap might possibly be either a simple gesture or the start of a more complicated one, the OS has to wait until the complicated one is no longer possible (timed out) before it can decide that the simple one is correct and should be delivered.